# 3 nodes cassandra with one being a spark master - to solve geospatial data or geographic data

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am looking for directions:

I have a cassandra database with latitude & longitude data. I need to search for data within a radius or a box coordinates around a point. I am using golang(gocql) client to query Cassandra.

I need some understanding regarding Spark and Cassandra as this seams like the way to go.

Is the following assumptions correct; I have 2 Cassandra nodes(the data in a replica of 2).

1. Should I then install an extra node and install Spark on this and then connect it to the other two existing Cassandra nodes containing the data(With the Spark Connector from DataStax).
2. And do the two existing Cassandra nodes need to have Spark workers installed on them to work with Spark Master node?
3. When the Spark setup is in place, do you query(Scala) the existing data and then save the data onto the Spark node and then query this with the gaoling(gocql) client?

Any directions is welcome

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geospatial Searching is a pretty deep topic. If it's just doing searches that you're after (not batch/analytics), I can tell you that you probably don't want to use Spark. Spark isn't very good at 'searching' for data - even when it's geospatial. The main reason is that Spark doesn't index data for efficient searches and you'd have to create a job/context (unless using job server) every time you'd want to do a search. That takes forever when you're thinking in terms of user facing application time.

Solr, Elastic Search, and DataStax Enterprise Search (Disclaimer I work for DataStax) are all capable of box and radius searches on Cassandra data and do so in near real time.

To answer your original question though, if the bulk of your analytics in general come from Cassandra data, it may be good idea to run Spark on the same nodes as Cassandra for data locality. The nice thing is that Spark scales quite nicely, so if you find Spark taking too many resources from Cassandra, you can simply scale out (both Cassandra and Spark).

> Should I then install an extra node and install Spark on this and then
>   connect it to the other two existing Cassandra nodes containing the
>   data(With the Spark Connector from DataStax).

Spark is a cluster compute engine so it needs a cluster of nodes to work well. You'll need to install it on all nodes if you want it to be as efficient as possible.

> And do the two existing Cassandra nodes need to have Spark workers
>   installed on them to work with Spark Master node?

I don't think they 'have' to have them, but it's a good idea for locality. There's a really good video on academy.datastax.com that shows how the spark cassandra connector reads data from Cassandra to Spark. I think it will clear a lot of things up for you: https://academy.datastax.com/demos/how-spark-cassandra-connector-reads-data

> When the Spark setup is in place, do you query(Scala) the existing
>   data and then save the data onto the Spark node and then query this
>   with the gaoling(gocql) client?

The Spark-Cassandra connector can communicate to both Cassandra and Spark. There are methods, saveToCassandra(), for example, that will write data back to Cassandra your jobs are processed. Then you can use your client as you normally would.

There are some really good free Spark + Cassandra tutorials at academy.datastax.com. This is also a good place to start: http://rustyrazorblade.com/2015/01/introduction-to-spark-cassandra/